# Matlab tcp/ip sockets with a basic license

Tags: matlab, sockets, tcp

Is there a way to use tcpip sockets in Matlab without using any add-on such as the [instrument control toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/instrument.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free TCP/UDP/IP toolbox available from MATLAB Central is made exactly for this:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcp-udp-ip-toolbox-2-0-6

Depending on your MATLAB version, you might have to make some source code edits as described in the discussion on the web page.  Some knowledge of C will help.

Another approach is taken by this MATLAB Central contribution.  It uses the Java framework that surrounds MATLAB instead:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25249-tcp-ip-socket-communications-in-matlab-using-java-classes